# Minimalist approach to Error Handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Would like suggestions on quick and easy error handling for asp.net mvc web application.

Comment: the quickest and easiest way is: don't! ... but of course, this solution is not recommended...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) in conjunction with an attribute that extends HandleError and logs the errors through ELMAH.  See this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute) for some ideas on how to get the HandleError attribute to work with ELMAH.  Dan Swatik also [blogged](http://danswatik.com/post/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-aspnet-mvc-handleerror-attribute) about this with an implementation based on the accepted answer in that question.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the old Application_Error method in the Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some good info in Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException() and Context.Request
    // that you can use in whatever you choose for 
    // your quick and easy logging/reporting
}
```

Obviously, you'll want to turn on customErrors too...

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/error">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/error/forbidden" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/notfound" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error" />
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the Nerd Dinner sample.  It uses a very neat and simple approach.

Answer (score 1):

I've just recently employed a very quick-n-dirty error reporting solution of my own that might give you some ideas...

Create a base controller class, lets call it `MyBaseController`. Have all your controllers inherit from this if you like, though this isn't necessary if you only have one controller.

Then you can override its partial `OnException` method and insert whatever kind of error reporting you might like, like to send yourself an email with the exception's ToString(). For example:

```
public MyOwnBaseController : Controller
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        SendAdminErrorAlert("Egads! An Error!", context.Exception.ToString());
        // I have a view named "500.aspx" that I will now show...
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        this.View("500").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
    }
}
```

I also found this article to be helpful: http://blog.dantup.me.uk/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-handleerror-attribute-custom.html in learning about all of this...

Good luck!
-f!

Comment: P.S., you can achieve practically the same 'quick-n-dirty' results from an Attribute you apply on your controllers (you can subclass the intrinsic HandleErrorAttribute i.e., [HandleError]) with practically the same amount of code...