# Determine whether or not ELMAH is enabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah

How can I determine programmatically whether or not [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is enabled?

Comment: could you explain your question? as it stands it makes no sense (to me).

Comment: Certainly.  I'm shipping ELMAH with a product, but it's the customer's decision whether or not to enable or disable it (in the web.config).  I need to know, when a page is loading, whether or not it's enabled.  I'm happy to answer any questions.

Comment: couldn't just read the relevant web.config section?

Comment: I thought about that, but I was hoping, maybe, for something else, especially considering that the web.config section that tells you whether or not it's enabled changes from IIS6 to IIS7.  For example, maybe something that gives me some sort of programmatic visibility to the handler for a given path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because:

> ELMAH can be dynamically added to a
>   running ASP.NET web application, or
>   even all ASP.NET web applications on a
>   machine, without any need for
>   re-compilation or re-deployment.

you should not need to detect whether it is present. Just write your logging code as if it was present, and if it's not, nothing will be logged.

Of interest?: [How to get ELMAH to work with ASP.NET MVC [HandleError] attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/779961#779961) (accepted answer is by ELMAH's author)

Comment: I need to show a link to elmah.axd.  If it's disabled, I don't want to show the link?

Comment: Can you make a web request to elmah.axd and check the status code? Maybe do this once and store the results in the Application variable for future uses.

Comment: @Greg: I was hoping to avoid that overhead.  Your solution is what I've coded so far, as it's the best I could think of.  I'm going to try looking through the loaded modules list, per Tadas' answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You can enumerate all loaded modules (via [HttpApplication.Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.modules.aspx)) and if Elmah module exists, then Elmah is enabled:

```
foreach (var m in Application.Modules) {
  if (m is Elmah.ErrorlogModule) {
   // ...
  }
}
```

Not sure. Haven't treed this.

Comment: I tried this, but Application.Modules wasn't available (it's been a while since I tried -- I might be remembering the details incorrectly, but I couldn't make it happen).  Do you have actual code that you've used to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Further to Tadas' answer, I came up with the following code that works for me (note that I have translated this from VB without checking if it compiles, so YMMV):

```
bool foundElmah = false;

foreach (var m in HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Modules) {
    var module = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Modules.Item(m);
    if (module is Elmah.ErrorLogModule || module is Elmah.ErrorMailModule || module is Elmah.ErrorFilterModule || module is Elmah.ErrorTweetModule) {
        foundElmah = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (foundElmah) {
    // do something here, like populate the application cache so you don't have to run this code every time
    return true;
} else {
    // store in application cache, etc.
    return false;
}
```

This also gets around the problems I had with getting a 401 response when requesting elmah.axd (I was using Windows Authentication), and is much faster, and doesn't assume a specific location for elmah.axd.