# ASP.NET logging Events in DB

Tags: asp.net, monitoring

Can ASP.NET's `System.web.Management` be used for logging events like user logins, password changes and access to certain resources? Should `system.Web.Management` be used for logging of errors and health monitoring instead?

I want to log events without re-inventing the whole thing. I know ELMAH is used for errors; can it be used for logging events too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article [ELMAH - Error Logging Modules And Handlers](https://web.archive.org/web/20170628223117/http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlers.aspx) on the now defunct DoNetSlackers:

> Error signaling is exposed via the ErrorSignal class, which provides a single overloaded method called `Raise`. Simply put, exceptions raised via the `ErrorSignal` class are not thrown, therefore they don't bubble up, but instead are only sent out to ELMAH, as well as to whomever subscribes to the Raise event of the `ErrorSignal` class.
>
> The code snippet below shows how to obtain an instance of the `ErrorSignal` class, which is unique per application and can be retrieved simply with the static `FromCurrentContext` method, and then use it to signal an exception.
>
> ```cs
> ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new NotSupportedException());
> ```
>
> The difference between signaling and throwing an exception is that in the first case no one will ever know about the error except ELMAH.

**Further Reading**:

- [How to get ELMAH to work with ASP.NET MVC `[HandleError]` attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779961/1366033)