# ELMAH in ASP.NET MVC 4 app in subfolder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, elmah, subdirectory

### Setup:

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app in a subfolder of the root folder (~/tracker).

I have ELMAH installed in the MVC app using NuGet.

### Dev Machine:

On my dev machine the website is at the root.  ELMAH works fine.

### Problem on the Server:

On the server, I can see the ELMAH page, but despite generating errors, no errors get logged.  It just says:  "No errors found".

It also appears without any styling.

### Web.config on Server:

The Elmah relevant bits on the server web.config are:

**configSections:**

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
```

**appSettings:**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="Admin" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="tracker/elmah" />
  </appSettings>
```

**httpModules:**

```
<httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
```

**system.webServer:**

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

**Finally:**

```
<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data/Elmah" />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
  </elmah>
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, solved this one:

Add write permissions to the ~/App_Data/Elmah folder.

As the meerkat said, simples.

I solved it by finding the following SO answer:

[Elmah.MVC does not log errors in production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11682295/271087)

There is also a guide for setting permissions on the ELMAH folder, or rather, a link to a guide in the accepted answer to that question.

What I can't get to work is the styling of the ELMAH pages.  Any suggestions?