# replacement for try catch(MyEx ex) in each action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need something that would work like this:

```
public ActionResult Ac()
{
  try {
   //stuff...
  }
  catch(MyException ex)
  {
   //handle
  }
}
```

but without putting try catch in each action method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to annotate your classes with HandleErrorAttribute - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.aspx.

If the functionality of the built in handler above isn't sufficient then you can define your own class which implements IExceptionFilter - the OnException method takes an ExceptionContext object with Result and HttpContext properties you can use to control the outcome, something like:

```
public class MyHandleErrorAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
  public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
  {
    Exception e = filterContext.Exception;

    // Do some logging etc. here

    if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled && filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
    {
      ViewResult lResult = ...
      filterContext.Result = lResult;
      filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
      filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
      filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
      filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Exception Filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs) for exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(MyException ), View = "MyErrView"))]
public ActionResult Ac()
{
    //stuff
}
```

but with a custom `HandleError` Attribute that handles the type of exceptions you are targeting. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/779961#779961) should give you a good start.