# ELMAH not logging errors in MVC 2 app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I'm using the suggestion from this question: [How to get ELMAH to work with ASP.NET MVC [HandleError] attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute)

I used Aziz's second code sample.

I ran the debugger to see what happens when an error occurs. The main function in the HandleErrorAttribute class is:

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
{
    base.OnException(context);

    var e = context.Exception;
    if (!context.ExceptionHandled   // if unhandled, will be logged anyhow
        || RaiseErrorSignal(e)      // prefer signaling, if possible
        || IsFiltered(context))     // filtered?
        return;

    LogException(e);
}
```

It reaches the if statement. `context.ExceptionHandled` returns true, `RaiseErrorSignal(e)` also returns true. IsFiltered is never reached, it just returns, and `LogException(e)` is never reached.

Has anyone run into this?

**EDIT:** Adding web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="0" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="AppDb" />
  </elmah>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppDb" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyDB.csdl|res://*/Models.MyDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>        
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your AppDb connection string is an Entity Framework connection string. I don't think ELMAH was written to recognize that format. Try giving ELMAH a standard SQL connection string and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Its short circut logic so it will stop at `|| RaiseErrorSignal(e)` and not evaluate `IsFiltered(context)`

The fact that `context.ExceptionHandled` is true indicates that you have explictly handled the exception yourself in your code with a try catch block. In this case you need to explicitly tell ELMAH to handle the error as well:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // do something 
    // etc

    // now tell ELMAH to handle it too
    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
}
```

Comment: While it is true that the call to RaiseErrorSignal(e) will skip IsFiltered(e) (if true), this will not prevent the exception from being recorded. RaiseErrorSignal(e) will record the exception via `ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().RaiseError(e)`, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `RaiseErrorSignal(e)` will record the error within ELMAH, `LogException(e)` does not need to be called if `RaiseErrorSignal(e)` returns true.

If ELMAH is properly configured both `RaiseErrorSignal(e)` and `LogException(e)` will result in an error being recorded. There are a few reasons for which `RaiseErrorSignal(e)` could return false, so `LogException(e)` exists merely as a backup should signaling fail.

If errors are still not showing up in ELMAH then chances are you have a problem with your configuration. Could you please post the relevant parts of your Web.config so we can have a look? Namely, please post the `<elmah />` section and also your http modules in `<system.web />` or `<system.webServer />` (if you're using an IIS7 environment).

### Update

As Erik King pointed out- your connection string 'AppDb' is for Entity Framework. It will not work as an ErrorLog connection string. If you add a standard connection string to your Web.config and point the ErrorLog at it, ELMAH *should* start logging correctly.

In case you were unaware- the ErrorFilter HttpModule must be declared after any modules it should filter. In your current Web.config if you were to define a filter it would only be applied to the ErrorLog module and not the ErrorMail module.

Comment: I've added my web.config to the original post.