# Elmah not storing stack trace when Facebook C# SDK throws Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, elmah

I'm using Elmah and the Facebook C# SDK (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)

Elmah has been working really well for me.  However, when the Facebook C# SDK throws an exception, the stack trace is not logged.

For example, when I throw this exception:

```
throw new FacebookApiException("this is a test");
```

The stack trace shows up properly in my browser (with debug turned on, of course), but Elmah doesn't store it.  Instead, this is all I see inside Elmah's "AllXml" column in the database:

```
detail="(Unknown) this is a test"
```

Usually, the detail attribute of the AllXml column will contain the full stack trace.  Do you know why this is?  How can I get Elmah to log the stack trace?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you making use of the MVC handle error attribute? Keep in mind that elmah logs only unhandled exceptions and you'd need to do some plumbing to log handled exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was caused by the override we had on FacebookApiException.ToString(). I removed the override. If you want, download the current source and give that a try. Let me know if it solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks Nathan.  That was exactly the problem.  I'm now getting the full stack trace stored in Elmah.  BTW, I had to modify the source code for Beta 5.06 to do this test because as soon as I threw a FacebookApiException() in Change Set 4927605c3ca6 (e.g. even as simple as throw new FacebookApiException("this is a test")), I got a stackoverlow exception.

Comment: Great. I will check out the other error, I threw that code in there late last night, so it probably needs to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the HandleError Attribute, you'll find this question really useful.

[ELMAH and HandleError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not using the HandleError attribute, but I'll have a look at that question.