# How do I get ASP.NET MVC to honor my customErrors settings?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, custom-error-pages, custom-errors

In the customErrors tag in my web.config, I am pointing to a controller.  In my controller I am redirecting to an external error page that is shared by multiple applications.

`<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Error/ServerError" mode="On">`

My controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult ServerError()
    {
        return Redirect("/Systems/ASPNETErrorHandling/ErrorPage.aspx");
    }

    public ActionResult ErrorTest()
    {
        throw new Exception("testing error handling");
    }
}
```

I'm calling Error/ErrorTest to test the error handling. But it always redirects to Views/Shared/Error.cshtml instead of redirecting to the controller I specified.

How do I get asp.net mvc to honor the defaultRedirect path in my customErrors settings?

UDPATE:  I'm also using ELMAH and overriding the HandleErrorAttribute as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/779961#779961).  I see from .Net Reflector that the base HandleErrorAttribute is setting Error as the view.  I don't think there's much I can do about it redirecting to Error.cshtml, or some other view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in the update to my question, I'm overriding the HandleErrorAttribute as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/779961#779961) in order to use ELMAH.  The base class automatically sets Error as the view.  So I just commented out `base.OnException(context);` and it works.  I don't know if it's the best solution, but I think it should work for my purposes.