# Who is invoking Error view and why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I got a MVC4 web application running and functioning properly since almost a year. Lately while reviewing production error logs, I found a lot of mysterious exception entries of same type. I checked logs and found these exceptions occur on both Beta and Production environment but not in local (seems like a hint - see findings 1 below).

There are two subsequent entries:

One is:

> Thread Id: 56, Message: Server_Exception - The view 'Error' or its
>   master was not found or no view engine supports the searched
>   locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/OrganizationUser/Error.cshtml
>   ~/Views/OrganizationUser/Error.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml

Second log entry is:

> Thread Id: 56, Message: Server_Exception - Stack Trace -    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

The exception is logged from Application_Error() in global.asax.cs like so:

```
            var ex = Server.GetLastError();

            if (ex != null)
            {
                logger.Log(string.Format("Server_Exception - {0}", ex.Message), LogCategory.Error);
                logger.Log(string.Format("Server_Exception - Stack Trace - {0}", ex.StackTrace), LogCategory.Error);
            }
```

And here is the snapshot of DB log messages:

[image]

**Finding/Analysis**:

1. Since the errors are logged only on remote server, it tells me it has got to do with how MVC handles remote errors? CustomErrors? - I don't have it defined it in web.config. Should I?
2. But the main question is, what caused the error to happen? And who is looking for view name Error? I know its hard for you to guess it but just checking my luck.
3. Another finding is the exceptions are logged after user has logged out. In my Login get form, I check isAuthenticated and if user is not authenticated I log a message 'Request not authenticated, showing login form.' and display login form. I can see this message in logged prior to above exception messages. So what's going on on login.cshtml that causes a contact to server which generates an error? I checked, login page and _Layout which has lots of server side code embedded but could not figure out what could cause server to try to load Error page.

I think internally MVC is calling Error page which does not exist in my source code hence these exception. But why 'Error' page? I thought to get advice on what to check in this case. Please advise if you want me to share anything that could help you understand my problem.

Comment: Do a project level search for "return View("Error")" or just "View("Error")" without the surrounding quotes. I'd bet you'll get a hit from the AccountController.

Comment: @rism - You lost the bet ;).... I actually did all possible combinations in solution. I suspect its something internal to framework who is calling Error view. Thanks for suggestion anyway.

Comment: Thankfully RussCam has come to the rescue with his most excellent answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are using the [**`System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) as this attribute will attempt to look for an `Error` view [**under certain conditions**](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/HandleErrorAttribute.cs) when an exception is thrown inside a controller action:

1. The currently executing action is not a child action
2. The exception has not already been handled *or* custom errors are enabled
3. When wrapped in a **[`HttpException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**, the exception has a 500 HTTP status code
4. The exception is an instance of [**`System.Exception`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

When all of the above are true, `System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute` creates a `System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo` instance, sets the ExceptionContext.Result property to a `ViewResult` which by default has the `ViewName` property set to `Error`.

Putting all of this together, In one of your controllers, an exception must be being thrown that meets all of the above points, in a controller action that has the `[HandleError]` attribute applied (maybe it's applied globally), which is attempting to find the `Error` view and failing to do so.

To know what the original exception is, you could put an `Error` view into your solution and write out the Exception message of the HandleErrorInfo model instance passed to the view (if the current user has the appropriate access controls).

Comment: Thank you very much.. @Russ Cam. I do have a global filter added. I got the clue, i will verify using your suggestion and come back. Thanks.

Comment: @SBirthare no worries. Let us know how you get on!

Comment: I have verified your point by implementing a custom handle error attribute with log messages and  forcing an exception from Login get action. The error messages logged are similar. I now deployed changes on remote server to see what actual exception is (original exception causing OnException being invoked).

Comment: Since I am handling exception by implementing Application_Error, I think I do not need HandleError attribute. What do you think sir?

Comment: @SBirthare `Application_Error` is a catch-all location for handling exceptions that can be handled within an ASP.NET application, MVC included and you can implement something like http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/57/getting-the-correct-http-status-codes-out-of-asp.net-custom-error-pages to do so

Comment: I do have something similar working for me, i was curious to know (as I removed today) what would be the impact of removing HandleErrorAttribute from global filter. I guess it should not impact but just wanted to double check. Thank you Russ. :)

Comment: @SBirthare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318104/errorattribute-vs-onexception-vs-application-error

Comment: @RussCam Re: 4. If I throw new Exception("Tester"); in the Index action of the HomeController it is handled.

Comment: @rism The rules above are straight from the source code - http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/HandleErrorAttribute.cs

Comment: @RussCam With greatest respect it seems you wrote from one angle ie when an "attribute WILL attempt to look for an Error view under certain conditions" but then listed the conditions for when it will not. So 4 re: source code it will ONLY handle when exception is of type Exception. And (2) it will only work if customErrors is on. IMHO I think you know exactly what you're talking about but have written it backwards for 2 of the points. So for (2) OR should be AND & for (4) IS NOT should just be IS.