# asp.net mvc: What makes error.cshtml run (and in the process not log to elmah)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

I am getting an error of some sort that causes error.cshtml to be displayed.

I dont see what settings are making it do that, plus I dont like the fact that elmah doesnt see the error either.

update: I have seen the elmah answer about how to get it to log things that get custom handled. What I don't understand is why I am getting into this state. I have nothing marked with HandleError attribute

update2: I think its because there is a global filter added using HandleErrorAttribute. THis effectively sets all controller actions to use the default error handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the wiki on the open source hosting for the ELMAH project, I found [this page](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC) about setting up ELMAH with MVC.  After reading through all the comments, at the very bottom, there was a link to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/779961#779961), which should help you get past the problem you are having.

Comment: With all due respect to Atif, who is awesome, I think Ivan Zlatev came up with a more elegant solution as an answer to the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/779961#5936867