# Elmah and ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

What are the steps required to set up elmah on an ASP.NET MVC 3 application?

1. nuget elmah
2. customize elmah (storage, etc)
3. [handle HandleError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/5936867#5936867)

Is that all? Is step 3 still necessary after nuget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out step 1 and 2 can be combined by nuget-ing "elmah on xml log", which will set up web.config so elmah will log errors into separate xml files. So no need to edit the config by hand at all, except to further customize elmah.

Step 3 is still necessary.

Comment: "elmah on xml log" is nugetted thusly: `Install-Package elmah.xml`

Comment: Does the .xml extension not negate the .mvc extension?

Comment: please [click](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/DotNetSlackersArticle) for other configuration when not using XML

Answer (score 9):

*Taken from : [HOW TO SETUP ELMAH.MVC WITH ASP.NET MVC 4 ?](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-setup-elmah-mvc-with-asp-net-mvc-4/)*

**What is Elmah ?**

ELMAH is an open source project whose purpose is to log and report unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET web applications.

**Why to use Elmah ?**

ELMAH serves as an unobtrusive interceptor of unhandled ASP.NET exceptions, those usually manifesting with the ASP.NET [yellow screen of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_Screen_of_Death).

So now we know what and why to use Elmah, Lets quickly get started on how to use Elmah with your ASP.NET MVC project.

**Step 1:** Right click on your solution and select the "Manage Nuget Packages" option [image]

**Step 2:** In the Nuget Package manager search for "Elmah" and install the [Elmah.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC) nuget extension.
[image]
The Nuget Package manager will download and add the required dlls and modify the web.config's `<appSetting>` for Elmah to wo[image]rk.

**Step 3:** That's it !! Your Elmah is now ready to test. I have generated a 404 to test if my Elmah works, ELMAH can be accessed by this url : *http://yourapp.com/elmah*.
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps :)

**Further Reading :**

- [Elmah on code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC)
- [Elmah.MVC 2.0.2 on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC)
- [Elmah.MVC on GitHub](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah.mvc)

Answer (score 7):

I used ELMAH in 2010 and 2011.  Now it is 2012, and I just added it to a new MVC 3 project and noticed the latest release made it much easier.

1. Nuget  Elmah.mvc
2. URL is  http://microsoft.com/admin/elmah
3. https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah.mvc/blob/master/README.md
4. http://www.beletsky.net/2011/03/integrating-elmah-to-aspnet-mvc-in.html
5. https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah.mvc

Comment: For the few people who still uses VB.NET: it doesn't support VB.NET MVC projects yet.

Comment: @Tom Stickel: the GitHub links are dead.

Comment: I did my best to find and update,  the microsoft.com part replace with your website as when I went to update Stackoverflow required a valid domain localhost would not even work.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that all? Is step 3 still necessary
>   after nuget?

You should really set up a database table in MSSQL or another reliable DB to feed your errors into so they can be retrieved and stored reliably.

Otherwise no, there is no real config needed but you would likely use Email as well as block specific annoying errors.

After a quick google I found this: http://kurtschindler.net/blog/post/Configuring-ELMAH-on-DiscountASPNET

Answer (score 1):

Elmah is already available for MVC 
http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Elmah.MVC/1.2

Answer (score 0):

basically, the hard bit is getting the Elmah config (in web.config) correct as the documentation is a little rough in my eyes