# The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've already set

```
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
```

I don't want to use any customeErrors,but why it still find Error view?

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Areas/OrderList/Views/OrderDetail/Error.aspx
~/Areas/OrderList/Views/OrderDetail/Error.ascx
~/Areas/OrderList/Views/Shared/Error.aspx
~/Areas/OrderList/Views/Shared/Error.ascx
~/Views/OrderDetail/Error.aspx
~/Views/OrderDetail/Error.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx
~/Areas/OrderList/Views/OrderDetail/Error.cshtml
~/Areas/OrderList/Views/OrderDetail/Error.vbhtml
~/Areas/OrderList/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
~/Areas/OrderList/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml
~/Views/OrderDetail/Error.cshtml
~/Views/OrderDetail/Error.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml
```

Comment: You have somwhere given this view for error in web.config.

Comment: Is it getting redirected from your Global.ascx Application_Error event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC problem with custom error pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265193/mvc-problem-with-custom-error-pages)