# Elmah is not triggering when custom errors is enabled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, elmah

When I have my custom errors disabled, Elmah is taking all exceptions that occur and logging them into my database and emailing me.

However, the second I change my web.config to:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Error">
</customErrors>
```

Elmah stops functioning.  It no longer logs exceptions to the database or anything, all I see is my custom error action being executed.

How can I have custom error messages and still have elmah log exceptions?  I am currently not doing any other exception intercepting besides Elmah.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Figured it out!

The reason this was occurring was because I had `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());` in `Global.asax`.  I don't know why this is there, but that was what was causing this to fail when custom errors was enabled.  Removing this line caused Elmah to work properly with custom errors.

Also, telling elmah to log "handled" errors also works, as described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/5936867#5936867).

I don't truely know the full ramifications of either option though.

Comment: If you have just one "generic" error page for all errors, you don't need a HandleErrorAttribute added, and so can remove it as you have.

Comment: Removing the standard filter seems to stop the web.config custom error redirect. Telling Elmah to log "handled" errors is definitely the better solution.

Comment: @owen how do you tell ELMAH to log handled exceptions?

Comment: Read KallDrexx's answer