# Redirecting from exception handling filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

I am using the filter from the solution posted to [Clean way to catch all errors thrown in an MVC 3.0 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711951/clean-way-to-catch-all-errors-thrown-in-an-mvc-3-0-application), and I was wondering how I could redirect to a view (of a simple error page that resides in /Views/Account/ErrorPage, as part of the AccountController), in that filter? It is reproduced below:

```
public class HandleExceptionsAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            var expception = filterContext.Exception;

            // Go to generic error page:

        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the filterContext.Result

```
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "<view name>",
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };
```

Here's the full method that captures the call that errors

```
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);

        var controllerName = (string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "<view name>",
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }
```

Comment: What should be the syntax of `"<view name>"`? I tried `"/Account/ErrorPage"` but that resulted in an error "master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations..."

Comment: put your view in the shared views