# ASP.NET MVC3 still looks for Error.aspx/.cshtml despite specifying my own view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

I have my ASP.NET MVC 3 application configured to redirect to an `Errors` controller with two actions -

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Errors/ApplicationError">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Errors/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

I have a couple of views that are rendered from each of the action methods:

- `/Views/Shared/NotFound.cshtml`
- `/Views/Shared/ApplicationError.cshtml`

In my `ErrorsController` `ApplicationError` action I do the following:

```
public ActionResult ApplicationError()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    return View();
}
```

This works and my `ApplicationError.cshtml` view is rendered, whatever exception happened is logged, all good.

However in ELMAH I see this extra error being logged:

> System.InvalidOperationException
>   The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/Views/Throw/Error.aspx ~/Views/Throw/Error.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx ~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx ~/Views/Throw/Error.cshtml ~/Views/Throw/Error.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml

Why is ASP.NET MVC still hunting for these views when I've already handled the error and my own view is successfully located and rendered?

**Additional Information:**

- I don't use the `[HandleError]` attribute anywhere
- I replaced `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());` in `Global.asax.cs` with `filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorAttribute());` as per [this advice](http://joel.net/logging-errors-with-elmah-in-asp.net-mvc-3--part-4--handleerrorattribute) which is based on this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/779961#779961) by Atif the [author of ELMAH](http://www.raboof.com/projects/elmah/).

Comment: Did you upgrade this from webmatrix or reference a webmatrix library?

Comment: Check that `HandleErrorAttribute` isn't applied globally. Look in `RegisterGlobalFilters` in `global.asax.cs`.

Comment: @AdamTuliper - no this is VS2010 Premium, the project has never seen WebMatrix.

Comment: What is the `ThrowsController` - i.e., is that the real name of your `ErrorController` or is it the controller that originally threw the exception?

Comment: @TheKaneda - ThrowsController is just a test controller that throw's an exception so I verify that that exception handling is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, although you've replaced `HandleErrorAttribute` with a derived class (`ElmahHandleErrorAttribute`), your custom attribute's `OnException` is probably still calling `base.OnException` - i.e. HandleErrorAttribute.OnException.

`HandleErrorAttribute.OnException` ignores the web.config settings completely (other than letting ASP.NET display the standard YSOD if customErrors are off), and sets the result of the action to a `ViewResult` with status code 500, and `View` set to "Error" (the default, when a `View` property hasn't been set on the attribute).

I.e., I'm guessing that something like this happens:

1. You throw an exception
2. `ElmahHandleErrorAttribute` picks it up, logs the exception, calls `base.OnException`
3. `HandleErrorAttribute.OnException` sets the result of the action to `ViewResult` with `View` set to "Error"
4. The ViewEngine fails to find this "Error" view, and so throws *a new* exception
5. ... which is logged by ELMAH, but not picked up by `ElmahHandleErrorAttribute` (because this exception occured outside the action)
6. Instead, ASP.NET itself picks it up, and uses the errorPages in web.config
7. ... calling /Errors/ApplicationError
8. ... which displays the view you want

... but not actually for the exception that you threw, rather the exception that the ViewEngine threw.

You may want to implement your own exception handling, rather than basing it on HandleError, if you want the web.config settings to be honored. Take a look at `HandleErrorAttribute` in the MVC sources ([here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72551#266465)) to see what needs to be done (and what shouldn't be done in your case).

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, meaning I am assuming that steps 1 to 8 occur just like that but... I am not using ELMAH... I have the standard CustomErrors and HealthMonitoring as error email manager. Do you happen to have any suggestion for this case? Thank you.