# The view 'Error' or its master was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, elmah

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out a workaround for this to no avail, so I thought I'd see if anyone here has an idea.

I'm using [Elmah in my ASP.NET MVC3 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute).  I'm using the exact same code from the accepted answer in the previous link.

I also have this code in my Global.asax for displaying error pages with the correct HTTP response:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The customErrors functionality provided by ASP.NET results in HTTP 302 redirects occurring which doesn't accurately reflect what the real HTTP code of the response was.
    /// This method can be used to handle specific HTTP codes without an intermediate redirect.
    /// </summary>
    protected void Application_Error() {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        var httpException = exception as HttpException;
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError();
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
        routeData.Values["action"] = "Error500";
        Response.StatusCode = 500;

        if (httpException != null) {
            Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            switch (Response.StatusCode) {
                case 403:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Error403";
                    break;
                case 404:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Error404";
                    routeData.Values["message"] = httpException.Message;
                    break;
                case 500:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Error500";
                    break;
            }
        }

        IController errorsController = new ErrorController();
        var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
        errorsController.Execute(rc);
    }
```

The problem occurs when I'm not on my (local) development machine (which initially made me think it was [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) related).  When an exception is thrown, Elmah handles the error and logs it correctly.  I also end up on the correct error page.  However, before ending up on the correct error page, I can see another intermediate exception being logged:

```
The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/Views/Articles/Error.aspx ~/Views/Articles/Error.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx ~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx ~/Views/Articles/Error.cshtml ~/Views/Articles/Error.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml
```

ASP.NET is trying to load up a default error page even though I am trying to handle it.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to prevent this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Don't call the `base.OnException(context);` method in your custom error handler that derives from `HandleErrorAttribute`. You no longer need it because you have implemented a custom error handling in `Application_Error`.

Comment: That did the trick.  After looking at the source code for the HandleErrorAttribute I could see that I needed to skip over some of the base functionality, but I think you're correct that I can just skip calling it altogether and be fine.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Same issue, different reason. This answer got me looking in the right direction.  I was using a <customErrors> with a redirect to a custom ErrorsController.  Turned out I also had a FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters() from the original project template, containing a filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()) line.  Removing that did it for me.

Comment: @JonathanN Man, you saved me!

Comment: @JonathanN tsm!

Answer (score 17):

I was having this same issue, but i wasn't executing base.OnException() anywhere.  Another possible solution was to remove this from `<system.web>` in my web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

Comment: If you don't have a customErrors in your web.config put one in explicitly with mode="Off"

Comment: Dave's comment was the answer for me

Answer (score 4):

If you use Elmah.MVC and want to use custom error pages, just change the below value to true in your Web.config:

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="true" />
```

This will keep Elmah logging enabled but stop it from trying to redirect to the default error page.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere your site is trying to navigate to ~/Error and it can't find it because it doesn't exist.

Trying removing or disabling **customErrors** in your Web.config.  I'm willing to be its set to the default of **on** and redirect to **~/Error**

If you want to post your Web.config (omitting any sensitive information) I can probably help.  I've dealt with similar issues with Elmah recently.

Comment: I actually think I know what the issue is, I'm just not sure about the best way to solve it.  I have my HTTP responses setup in my Global.asax, but, the OnException override is executing a result of its own.  By default that result is the view that it can't find, because I deleted it.  So I maybe need to set the `context.Result` property in my OnException override, but I don't know how to do that with my custom errors controller that I have.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Elmah.mvc, then it will help to change this settings to true:

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="true" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="true" />
```

Comment: Doesn't this disable Elmah?