# Use Elmah to Catch Unhandled Exceptions using IExceptionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah

I'm trying to convert some code I found for MVC to work in regular Asp.Net. In short I want to be able to log handled exceptions using Elmah, without having to call a logging method every time the exception occurs. I've looked all around for this and all the solutions I find use MVC. I found a simple and elegant one here and even though my application uses MVC for client side calls, it's not a full blown MVC project so I guess it's not going to work or I'm missing something.

So here is the code

```
public class ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException (ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // Log only handled exceptions, because all other will be caught by ELMAH anyway.
        if (context.ExceptionHandled)
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception);
    }
}
```

and

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters (GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter());
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

The post from:
[How to get ELMAH to work with ASP.NET MVC [HandleError] attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/5936867#5936867)

Says to place the second code block in the global.asax file. The event never gets called for me so I'm wondering if I have to call it myself and if I do then what am I passing to it? I'd prefer to know what the equivalent for regular asp net would be as I'm not familiar with MVC although since i have a reference to the MVC dll I would be open to trying to get it to work 'as is' if someone has ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Since regular ASP.NET has a different pipeline for loading pages, the filter is not applied to those page requests. However, it will execute for the MVC specific routes, and the solution you've found is indeed the best. There are also NuGet packages that have same implementations.

The standard ELMAH package should already catch all unhandled exceptions, also for ASP.NET Forms applications. I recommend you to follow the standard documentation for setup.