# Custom HandleErrorAttribute - How to set result without ASP.NET overriding it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on making my ASP.NET MVC apps handle HTTP status codes correctly and when needed display a view for them.  I'm avoiding all of the out of the box error page handling since it isn't semantic (e.g. the framework always performs a 302 redirect with `customErrors`).

I have an `AuthorizeAttribute` and `ActionFilterAttribute` which are both working correctly and my custom view is displayed.  However, my `HandleErrorAttribute` isn't working quite right.

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context) {
    HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

    var e = context.Exception;

    if (e is HttpException) {
        var httpException = (HttpException)e;
        httpStatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)httpException.GetHttpCode();
    }

    context.Result = MyResultBuilder.SetViewByHttpCode(context.HttpContext.Request, httpStatusCode, context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState);
}
```

I am setting the `Result` property, but at some point the pipeline is overriding my result as I end up with a Yellow Screen of Death (YSOD) instead of the view result that I defined.

How do I set a custom view result in the `HandleErrorAttribute`?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the [ExceptionHandled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.exceptioncontext.exceptionhandled%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) property to true;

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bond.  The one issue with that approach is something that I failed to point out in my original post: Elmah.  I'm using Elmah for my error logging and according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute the suggested approach is to signal errors so they can be handled later in the pipeline.  Any suggestions for working around that or am I out of luck?

Comment: Why can't you use the answer to the question you linked? I.e directly logging the error to ELMAH through the API?