# how to redirect to default error page after ELMAH implemented?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah

I have implemented ELMAH with help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/779961#779961) (@Ivan Zlatev answer). It is working fine. But now I need to redirect default error page with error message.

How can I do this?. I was reading with ELMAH, we can not implement custom error page. Is it true?

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
 {
     filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter());
     filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
 }

public class ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // Log only handled exceptions, because all other will be caught by ELMAH anyway.
        if (context.ExceptionHandled)
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Elmah is for logging errors, Creating custom error page is a different step. You can do it using your web.config

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
   <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="500.aspx" />
   </customErrors>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And then you will have to implement the error.aspx 400.aspx 500.aspx pages.