# How to turn off automatic Elmah logging?

Tags: .net, logging, error-handling, webforms, elmah

I'd like to disable automatic exception logging in Elmah, while leaving manual logging enabled, e.g.

```vb
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext.Raise(ex)
```

My situation is nearly identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25659475), with the sole difference being that I'm using XML logging instead of SQL. I'm also generating a unique ID for the exception that I'm using for tracking purposes.

When I disable the `ErrorLog` module in `Web.config`, however, as suggested in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957433), I also lose the ability to manually log the exception. Nothing gets logged at that point.

Here's the code from `Global.asax`:

```vb
Sub Application_Error(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Dim sCode As String

  sCode = Utils.NewId(IdModes.AlphaNumeric)

  Try
    Throw New LinkedException(sCode, Me.Server.GetLastError)

  Catch ex As LinkedException
    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext.Raise(ex)

  Finally
    Me.Server.ClearError()

  End Try

  Me.Context.Redirect($"~/oops/{sCode}")
End Sub
```

...and here's `LinkedException`:

```vb
Imports System.Web

Public Class LinkedException
  Inherits HttpException

  Public Sub New(ExceptionCode As String, ex As HttpException)
    MyBase.New(ex.ErrorCode, $"[{ExceptionCode}] {ex.Message}", ex)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Is it possible to turn off automatic logging but leave manual turned on? When I turn on automatic I get two entries, when I turn it off I get none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it's best to let ELMAH do the heavy lifting and not use `Application_Error` at all.

```vb
Imports Elmah

Public Class Global_asax
  Inherits HttpApplication

  Private Sub ErrorLog_Filtering(Sender As Object, e As ExceptionFilterEventArgs)
    Dim oContext As HttpContext
    Dim oError As [Error]
    Dim sCode As String

    oContext = TryCast(e.Context, HttpContext)
    sCode = Utils.NewId(IdModes.AlphaNumeric)

    If oContext.IsNotNothing Then
      ' Create a customized error containing the error code
      oError = New [Error](e.Exception, oContext) With {.User = $"[{sCode}] { .User}"}

      ' Log the customized error
      ErrorLog.GetDefault(oContext).Log(oError)

      ' Dismiss the incoming exception so
      ' we don't get a duplicate entry
      e.Dismiss()
    End If

    Me.Response.Redirect($"~/oops/{sCode}", True)
  End Sub
End Class
```