# How to write a custom C# attributes to handle exceptions in a handler

Tags: c#

I have created a custom atttribute class like this

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public class AMemento : Attribute
    {

        public void method(){
        try {

        }
        catch (Exception) {

        }}
    }
```

and I am planning to use this custom attribute in a handler to catch any exceptions occur their as follows

```
    [AMemento]
    [Authorize]
    public JsonResult GetWeatherData()
    {
         //// code here which throw an exception
    }
```

I want to know the way to complete the custom attribute class to capture an exception thrown in GetWeatherData() handler. Is it possible to implement like a higher order function like in python ?

Comment: I think that you need ExcetpionFilter rather than simple attribute.

Comment: I will have a look , thank you :)

Comment: The following MSDN link is might help you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iexceptionfilter%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: exception is not passing to customized attribute method

Comment: I assume GetWeatherData is an action on an MVC controller, is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the MVC framework there is the [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) class.  This you can extend and override the [OnException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.onexception(v=vs.118).aspx) method.  A good example of this is the in the [Elmah MVC](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah-mvc/) project where they have a [HandleErrorAttribute](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah-mvc/blob/master/src/Elmah.Mvc/HandleErrorAttribute.cs) class.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute) also provides some example of HandleErrorAttribute, again in the context of ELMAH but it should be relatively obvious that in overriding OnException you can provide your custom exception logic for MVC actions.