# Elmah in an Azure Web Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, elmah

I'm trying to migrate a bunch of ASP.Net MVC web sites to Azure.  In the process I've noticed that Elmah does not function on any of those web sites.  I created the simplest case possible to test with and found that it doesn't work either.

On Azure I created a "standard tier" web site, I did no further configuration to it.

In Visual studio I created a new ASP.NET MVC web site.  I added the Nuget "Elmah" package.  I changed one line in the web.config to:

```
<security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
```

This change was done to allow me to view the elmah page.  (I know insecure, but just trying to prove a point)

I also changed the controller so that clicking the about menu generates an exception.  Otherwise this is a generic MVC web site. Locally everything works great and I can generate the exception and see it show up on the Elmah.axd page, but once I deploy the site to Azure no data ever appears on the Elmah page.

I have left the sample online for demonstration purposes:

1. Start at: http://testelmah.azurewebsites.net/elmah.axd
2. Next go to: http://testelmah.azurewebsites.net and click about. You should see an error message indicating an exception occured.
3. Go back to: http://testelmah.azurewebsites.net/elmah.axd
4. Be puzzled that Elmah isn't working

I've spent hours googling for a solution and it seems that Elmah just works for everyone else in Azure.  What am I missing?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute

Comment: Since the question is answered, I have deleted the example web site.  Leaving the links because it helps understand the context of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your problem is, that you're running with custom errors enabled and/or using the HandleErrorAttribute. You probably get a yellow screen of death when running on localhost and the "nice" error page when running on Azure. Your custom errors may be configured in web.release.config.

You should consider using the [Elmah.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/) NuGet package, because this helps you log errors in ELMAH when running with custom errors and the HandleError attribute from ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Correct on both the reason and the suggestion.  Thanks!